# $\gcd(0.5,2.5)=1$ or $0.5$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

So I got this question in my exams. 
**Find the HCF of $0.5$ and $2.5$.** 
My friends are saying that answer would be $0.5$. 
I wrote $1$ because I couldn't see any factor bigger than it common to both.
Moreover, I have one more point that domain of $\gcd$ is positive integers.  
So there can be two things, whether, the question is wrong, and even if we extend $\gcd(a,b)$ to rational numbers, answer would be $1$, because $1$ is bigger than $0.5$. 
So please clear my doubts.

Comment: I agree with you. The formal definition of gcd does specify the domain as integers. Your reasoning is fine. I would stick to it

Comment: Does the definition of the gcd apply to non-integer rationals?

Comment: That is what I am saying. @GudsonChou, I got this question in my exam, so let us assume it does. But still $1$ **will** be greater than $0.5$.

Comment: I prefer to say this is off-topic, since it certainly not a question about math. What can anyone do, in mathematical way, if the concept itself is not well-defined and can't be improved (since your teacher is not here and can't tell what *HCF* means to him/her)?

Comment: Isn't MSE a site to get mathematical concepts cleared? Where would I go then? I think this is a topic worth discussing. And again, I clear, that I only want to know the logic and answer behind the "title" question. @Asydot.

Comment: One consistent definition they could be using is "The $\gcd$ is the smallest number writable as a sum (with integer coefficients) of the arguments" as in Bézout's identity - i.e. using $a|b$ to mean there is an integer so that $na=b$. This isn't the most unreasonable definition (since we get to keep Euler's algorithm), but it doesn't go without saying.

Comment: Having a HCF of two numbers that is greater than the minimum of the two would seem problematic to my mind would be my reason for supporting the answer of .5 here.

Comment: Why? @JBKing. Reasoning or logic would help?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal: The point is that, with the usual definition, the question is nonsense; but if your professor has given a reasonable definition, then of course the situation is different. So you may try to see if your professor indeed gave another definition of gcd; if not, then the question is nonsense. :)

Comment: Because then there would be the question of how well could you really eliminate the numbers greater than a value? For example, could be there numbers greater than a million that divide 2 or 3? Could you exhaustively demonstrate that for each value without running out of time in your life? While this may seem ridiculous, it is an extension of where this could go.

Comment: In the post above, it is explained in an elementary way how to extend the concept from the integers to the rationals in a way that you lack generality but preserve non-triviality. Since it seems your interest is not of thorough and general discussion, I recommend you see the above post. Keep in mind that this is not the "right" (meaning: generalized) way of talking about $\text{gcd}$. For that, see my answer and/or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#The_gcd_in_commutative_rings

Comment: @AloizioMacedo: In the possible duplicate you pointed to, I gave a historically-based answer that would indeed make the gcd equal to $0.5$. That said, in current common usage, the notion is restricted to pairs of natural numbers.

Comment: Please see my answer. My confusions are cleared. Thank you all for contributing. (I got to that before that duplicate mark).

Comment: I think the question has a severe flaw in itself, and I'm ashamed myself that I didn't ask it in my first comment:

**What is your teacher's definition of GCD?**

Comment: I don't think it is necessary now, all the confusions are cleared. And still, my teacher was wrong. We had no reason for his answer's support. He just had a book, which used the traditional method of finding the GCD, *his only support*.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal This can serve as a reference for other people eventually. Your confusions may have been cleared, but the question has its own existence now. Leaving a signifcant hole such as an ambiguous definition (or rather, the **inexistence** of one) in the question can be very harmful to potential confused people, as it was to you.

EDIT: For example: you linked a plethora of links, each of which provided only an algorithmical way to solve, without a proper definition. This may have confused you.

Comment: Ok, I understand. So what things I have to clarify?

Comment: The definition of GCD you are using.

Comment: If you want to know my professor's logic. All I can provide is "And he has no logic, he just says that
"$1$ is a universal factor, it is for all. So here the answer is $0.5$".

Comment: If you want, I can delete the convo in between, and set the question simply as finding the gcd of $(0.5,1.5)$

Comment: The duplicate is half of the story. There are two reasonable things one might mean when the $\gcd(1/2, 5/2)$ comes up in a problem. The linked duplicate is one of those two (and in that meaning, $1$ does not divide either number evenly). In the other, both $1$ and $1/2$ (along with *every* nonzero rational number) are correct, equivalent answers to $\gcd(1/2, 5/2)$.

Answer (score 5):

This question
has the assumption
that a factor of
a non-integer rational number
can be specified.
In particular,
it assumes that
factors of 0.5 and 2.5
can be specified.

I believe that this shows
a fundamental misunderstanding
on the part of the creator of the question.

The algorithm stated is this:

$HCF(a/b, c/d)
=\frac{\gcd(a, c)}{\operatorname{lcm}(a, c)}
=\frac{\gcd(a, c)}{ac/\gcd(a, c)}
=\frac{\gcd^2(a, c)}{ac}
$.

This does not even use the denominators!

To use Pauli's famous phrase,
this is not only not right,
it is not even wrong.

Answer (score 3):

First and foremost, I would ask you to edit your question in order to only present itself as a question. Other details are not only irrelevant but also distracting.

Now, two ways of defining $d=\text{mdc}(a,b)$ are:

1. $d$ satisfies:

   - $d | a$, $d| b$
   - $ e|a, e|b \implies e | d $

or

2. $d$ is a generator of the ideal generated by $a,b$.

My algebra may be a bit rusty... so these definitions may not be equivalent when dealing with some spaces (for instance, non-PID's), but they are for our discussion here.

There is a problem when we try to apply these definitions for $\mathbb{Q}$. If you check, given any two (non-trivial) numbers, *any* number will be a $\text{gcd}$ of both. The discussion is quite trivial in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Whereas, in $\mathbb{Z}$, generators of ideals are defined up to a sign (since units are only $1$ and $-1$), hence there is no problem in defining $\text{gcd}$ well enough.

Comment: So? We cannot quite define $\gcd$?

Comment: **For fractions**?

Comment: You can, but it would imply non-uniqueness (in a non-solvable way. GCD is also non-unique for the integers, but since they differ by a sign change; you simply pick the positive). Not only that, it would imply high triviality. For example, $10=gcd(0.5,2.5)$, $2323=gcd(0.5,2.5)$, $\frac{1}{10^6}=gcd(0.5,2.5)$ etc.

Comment: Sorry I cannot see how $10$ and $2323$ are the HCFs?

Comment: Read the definition I gave.

Comment: How $10|0.5$...

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}=10.\frac{1}{20}$

Comment: But we would get a non-integer as quotient then?

Comment: You started with non-integers so I'm not sure I see the point there.

Answer (score 2):

I got my answer on my own! After a lot of thinking (elementary terms only), I deduced that the answer **is** indeed $0.5$. Because, 
 
first and the foremost, we look at Euclid's Division Lemma, which states that any positive integer $a$ can be expressed as $bq+r$ where $b,q$ and $r$ are **integers**! 
 
Now even if we extend this to rational numbers, $q$ **will** indeed remain integer. (think it over, you will get why, because if it would not have been the case then gcd would have been non-sensical). 
 
Coming back to my question, $\gcd(\frac12,\frac32)$, if we take $1$ to be the common factor, $1$ **is not** a common factor because on dividing $\frac12$ by $1$, we get a fraction, not an **integer**. Same with $\frac32$. And the largest number satisfying this rule (quotient is an integer) is **indeed** $0.5$. 
Thus, $$\gcd(\frac12,\frac32)=\frac12$$
P.S.: *Sorry, if any one already got there*.

Comment: At least you got there.